# Tear between mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging

Sorry my English is not very good. I'm a beginner and use Blender 2.79b.

I found a 3D character composed of several parts (torso, arm and leg).
On each part i have a texture file so i do not want to transform these 3 meshs into one.
Problem, when i add a skeleton and move the arm, a tear is formed between the parts (see example image between arm and torso).
How to solve this problem?

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have added material on each mesh, and I have linked all mesh and now it's OK.